# SSD freezes every Monday at 00:00 local time

Tags: ssd, hardware, samsung

I have this SSD:

```
$ lsscsi --verbose 9
[9:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      Samsung SSD 860  4B6Q  /dev/sdb 
  dir: /sys/bus/scsi/devices/9:0:0:0  [/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:01:00.2/0000:02:06.0/0000:07:00.0/ata10/host9/target9:0:0/9:0:0:0]
```

It generally works fine, but every Monday at 00:00 local time it glitches. If the computer is turned on and running Ubuntu 18.04 at 00:00, then every disk access is failing for a few minutes, and then it restores to normal. Kernel messages look like this:

```
[33597.552222] ata10.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x438c0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
[33597.552228] ata10.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[33597.552236] ata10.00: cmd 61/68:30:b0:a0:7d/01:00:05:00:00/40 tag 6 ncq dma 184320 out
                        res 40/00:01:00:4f:c2/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
[33597.552239] ata10.00: status: { DRDY }
[33597.552294] ata10: hard resetting link
[33598.028219] ata10: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[33598.028480] ata10.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
[33598.030650] ata10.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
[33598.032509] ata10.00: configured for UDMA/133
[33598.032534] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#12 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[33598.032538] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#12 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[33598.032541] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#12 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
[33598.032544] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#12 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 01 15 57 88 00 00 38 00
[33598.032548] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 18175880 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[33598.032559] ata10: EH complete
[33598.032642] ata10.00: Enabling discard_zeroes_data
```

This message sequence repeats 4 times with 30 second interval, and after that it's back to normal.

If the computer is turned off at 00:00, then the problem is observed when it's turned on for the first time on Monday. GRUB loads fine from the same disk, but when Ubuntu starts loading, it seems the disk stops working, and the startup hangs. After hitting reset, it starts up normally.

What can cause such weird behavior?

Comment: Is there anything interesting in `/etc/cron.weekly`?

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're having one of two issues...

1. The firmware in your Samsung 860 SSD needs updating.
2. You're having NCQ errors, and require a patch.

**Firmware**

Download `Samsung Magician` [here](https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/download/tools/), and check your Samsung firmware.

**fsck**

Let's check your file system for errors...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**NCQ**

The NCQ error can be seen here...

```
[33597.552222] ata10.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x438c0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
[33597.552228] ata10.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[33597.552236] ata10.00: cmd 61/68:30:b0:a0:7d/01:00:05:00:00/40 tag 6 ncq dma 184320 out
                        res 40/00:01:00:4f:c2/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
[33597.552239] ata10.00: status: { DRDY }
[33597.552294] ata10: hard resetting link
```

Native Command Queuing (NCQ) is an extension of the Serial ATA protocol allowing hard disk drives to internally optimize the order in which received read and write commands are executed.

Edit `sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub` and change the following line to include this extra parameter. Then do `sudo update-grub` to write the changes to disk. Reboot. Monitor hangs, and watch `/var/log/syslog` or `dmesg` for continued error messages.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash libata.force=noncq"
```

Comment: The problem does not occur after disabling NCQ. Still, it's a mystery for me what caused it. I don't think it can be a firmware problem, since the freezing occurred only when loading into Ubuntu, but not when loading into another system. The only thing that runs weekly according to journalctl is `fstrim` - can it somehow cause freezes?

Comment: @deesklo Glad it's working better for you now. Still could have a SSD firmware issue. Do check it out.

Answer (score 0):

The timing is due to the [fstrim](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Solid_state_drive#Periodic_TRIM) service that periodically trims unused data blocks to refresh SSD performance. By default it's configured to run once a week on Monday at 00:00.

To see the service run:

```
systemctl status fstrim.timer
```

On a properly designed drive it would be completely correct and harmless, but Samsung SSDs have a buggy implementation of NCQ which interacts badly with trimming. Whether or not the bug manifests may vary depending on your motherboard's storage controller, or other mysterious factors.

Samsung likes to advertise that they fixed the bug, but they didn't. I don't know. It's a whole thing. See:

- https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=203475
- https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=201693

If you know you only get issues when the periodic trim runs, and not at other times, you might prefer to renable NCQ for better performance overall, and just disable trim:

```
systemctl stop fstrim.timer
systemctl disable fstrim.timer
```